# How do i create a local CVS repository in Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, cvs

And also how do versioning can help me manage my project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a [CVS repository](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/) outside of Eclipse.  [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) and [Git](http://git-scm.com/) are newer source code version control systems you might want to consider.

A source code version control system maintains more than one version of your source code.  This is useful when you want to have software versions, as well as when you want to back out a change you made to an earlier version.

As far as installation instructions, here's an online [CVS manual](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/).